# how scanf with character class work without format specifier

Tags: c, scanf

```
char info[30];
scanf("%79[^\n]", info);
printf("%s", info);
```

This code works successfully. But

```
scanf("%79", info);
```

will not work. I need to modify it like that:

```
scanf("%79s", info);
```

I understand that first code snippet means read till newline. But how does it work without "s" format specifier?

Comment: `But how does it work without "s" format specifier?` `will not work` it doesn't.

Comment: *"But how does it work without "s" format specifier?"* - that's not what the first example is doing. Did you read any documentation on `scanf` format specifiers? [Try this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). The chart on the format string should be highly informative.

Comment: The `"%79[^\n]"` works without `s` because there are two entirely different format specifiers with quite different behaviour. One is `%s` and another is `"%[...]"`. If you place `s` on its own in the format string, then the letter `'s'` in the input must be matched to it. So `"%79[^\n]s"` first reads up to a newline, and then `"s"` matches a single `'s'` in the input. But since the next character is a newline, it won't match.

Comment: `info[30]` is too small for `"%79[^\n]"`.  Use `"%29[^\n]"`.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets "[^\n]" itself is a specifier like "s" in "%s".

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Answer (score 1):

> how does it work without "s" format specifier?

It works because it's a completely different format specifier.  It has nothing to do with `%s`.

Most `scanf` format specifiers are based on a single letter, perhaps along with some modifier letters, like `%d`, or `%f`, or `%lf`.

But `%[…]` is different: it's got a `[`, and a set of characters to scan, and a `]`.  The complete specifier ends at the `]`.

All `scanf` format specifiers take an optional "width" specifier between the `%` and the other stuff.  So `%79s` is a length-limited version of `%s`, and `"%79[^\n]"` is a length-limited version of `%[…]`.

You will sometimes see people write things like `"%[^\n]s"`, as if `[^\n]` is some kind of modifier that modifies `%s`.  But it's not; that `s` at the end of `"%[^\n]s"` is in error.